# cant open file .exe 1104

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using sfml 2.0. I know I can ask on there forum but I don't think it has anything to do with linking a library wrong because I compiled an example project fine and it's pretty much the exact same thin I'm just trying to incorporate an external class. I get this when I try to compile

> 1> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\brr\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\sfmlgame\Release\sfmlgame.exe'

My code is as follows:

main.cpp:

```
#include "functions.h"
int main()
{
    functions func;
    std::cout << "Testing 123, testing 123!";
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        func.window.clear();
        func.window.draw(shape);
        func.window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

functions.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include<SFML\Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class functions
{
public:
    functions(void);
    ~functions(void);
    void Events();
    void Window();
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Event event;
};
```

functions.cpp:

```
#include "functions.h"
functions::functions(void)
{
}

functions::~functions(void)
{
}

void functions::Window(){
    window.setSize(sf::Vector2u(800,600));
    window.setTitle("Test");
}

void functions::Events(){
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does directory `C:\Users\brr\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\sfmlgame\Release` exists and writeble ? Can you copy any file to it using explorer or other file-manager ?

Comment: try do clean & build, is this error then reported too?

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities.
1. You **don't have access** to the `C:\Users\brr\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\sfmlgame\Release` directory. You can check by attempting to create a new file in this location.

2.The process is already in use. Run task manager(`start->run->taskmgr`), and check if `sfmlgame.exe` is running. **If yes, kill the process**.

Comment: Had this because was launching the program via ctrl+f5 in visual studio, for maximum performance.  After I closed this program, it worked. Ctrl+f5 runs the code without attaching a debugger. The usual f5 attaches a debugger which is a lot slower (even in Release mode).

Answer (score 3):

1. go to task manager
2. go to Processes tab
3. look for the desired exe file
4. click on *End Processes*
5. build for project again

Answer (score 2):

One usually gets this error when they have the program (`sfmlgame.exe`) already open/running, so visual studio can't replace it with the newly compiled one. Close the program if you are already running it, then try again.